# How can i update a widget only when i press a button in an activity from within the main app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget

I have made an app consisting of 5 activities . I just wanted to know how I could update a widget only when I press a button in the present in an activity in the main app

Answer (score 1):

You need a `reciever` for your widget declared in the manifest.xml:

```
    <receiver
        android:label="MyIP Widget"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:name="Widget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
```

That block should be inside the application block.

In my example the widget updates upon connectivity state change. You can replace that with a custom intent. And, from your activity, you need to send that intent to update the widget, something like this:

```
  Intent i = new Intent();
  i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
  context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

where

```
public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST";
```

you can pick the name that you want.

And make sure to add the same name in the reciever:

```
<action android:name="jason.wei.custom.intent.action.TEST" />
```

UPDATE:
to receive you broadcast, you need this method in your Widget class

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

...

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context,intent);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), Widget.class);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    if (appWidgetIds != null && appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
        onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```

The code above may look a bit complex but it is needed to update all the instances of your widget (the user may have your widget on different home screens or even at one screen).

As you can see, it calls the onUpdate method, where you set the actions you want to be executed to update the widget:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);    
//your update code here
}
```

Comment: How can i recieve this brodcast in the widget class can you help me with that too??